# DependencyProperties in ViewModel visible for caller

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I'm developing a user control using MVVM pattern. I need to expose a couple of DPs that have to be visible for a user of the control. I want them to be declared within the ViewModel, but when I do that, DPs become invisible for a user who wants to use them in xaml.

Is it possible to work with DPs conveniently using MVVM when developing a UserControl?

Comment: The declared DPs must be in code behind to be accesible for that usercontrol.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: @EngineerSpock Yes John is right that the DP must be in the code behind. The DP defined in the code behind will be visible to the user of the control. So why use MVVM?